# Find out coffee level radius

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

I have a plastic cup with the dimensions:

**H**eight = 7.89 cm
base **r**adius = 2.10 cm
top **R**adius = 3.25 cm

With the formula,
$$
vCup = \dfrac{\pi H}3(R^2+Rr+r^2)
$$
I could calculate to fit **180mL** in the cup.

Applying the same formula,
$$
vCup = \dfrac{\pi 4.56}3(2.25^2+2.25 * 2.10+2.10^2)
$$
I could fit **67.68mL** of coffe in the cup.

Question:
I would like a formula to calculate the radius according to height, that is, the coffee level, since I have the maximum and the minimum radii.

Why is it complicated to measure this in everyday life?

Comment: Sorry, this was translated from Portuguese to English, please feel free to edit.

Comment: You need to solve a quadratic equation to find $R_{coffee}$ as you know volume, base radius and height. This is not too hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set up the equation below

$$\frac{h}{H} = \frac{x-r}{R-r}$$

to obtain the radius, given height $h$

$$x = r+ \frac{h}{H}(R-r)$$

where $R$ and $r$ are the maximum and the minimum radii, respectively, and $H$ is the height of the cup.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.

Comment: Can you explain how radius $x$ at height $h$ varies linearly with $h$?

Comment: If you draw a diagram, you could identify a pair of similar triangles, which gives the linear relationship.

Comment: I could think it's easy for $(R^2+r^2)$ (related to circles, the solid is part of a cone), but the $Rr$ part confuses me.